# How do I reduce opacity of geometry that is hidden from view?

Tags: three.js, alphablending, depth-buffer

I have a 3D model of a house with some lines draw on it in teal. I'd like to reduce the opacity of lines that should not be visible to the camera because they are hidden behind parts of the roof.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://twitter.com/garrettkjohnson/status/1422220372762501129

Comment: Have a look at this [example (webgl_postprocessing_outline)](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=outlin#webgl_postprocessing_outline). Hidden outlines are rendered with lower opacity. Maybe you can adapt the code to to work not just for outlines but edges/geometry in general.